# Html Mp4 Audio Work But Not Video

Tags: html, mp4

With this code i obtain a video player in my web page but work only the audio. It shows me a black screen while the audio is running. Video files are good, i checked more than one time.

```
<video width="400" height="400" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="PetShop_Preview.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="PetShop_Preview.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<object data="PetShop_Preview.mp4" width="400" height="400">
  <embed width="400" height="400" src="PetShop_Preview.swf">
</object>
</video>
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: What browser are you using and what is your DOCTYPE?

Comment: The browser is Chrome and in my jsp i put this: <!DOCTYPE HTML>.

Comment: What MIME types is the server sending for those files? In chrome look on the Network tab of the developers tools.

Comment: Only "text/html" and "audio/ogg".

Comment: Well there's your problem. You need to be serving that as video/ogg.

Comment: What webserver are you using? Apache? Nginx? Lighttpd?

Comment: Unfortunately, you are using the one server that I have no knowledge of. I promise you that if you figure out how to change the MIME-Type that is being served the video will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the MIME-Type that the resource is being served as. Make sure that it matches the type attribute that you have provided.

To do that in tomcat you will have to edit the web.xml file. http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml.MimeMapping